# How can I check if data exist in table and update a value, if not insert data in table using MariaDB?

Tags: python, database, mariadb

I have 2 tables. First table contains some products and the second table is used for temporary data storage. Both tables have the same column names.

```
Table `products`: contains this columns
                 - id (unique, autoincrement)
                 - name
                 - quantity
                 - price
                 - group
Table `temp_stor`: contains this columns
                 - id (unique, autoincrement)
                 - name
                 - quantity
                 - price
                 - group
```

I want to get from the first table one row (name,quantity,price,group) and insert it into the second table if the data does not exist. If the same data exists in `temp_stor` I want to update only one column (quantity).

For example:
I take from `products` the following line `('cola','1','2.5','soda')`, I want to check the `temp_stor` to see if the line exist. `temp_store` table looks like this:

```
('milk 1L','1','1.5','milks')
('cola','1','2.5','soda')
('bread','1','0.9','pastry')
('7up','1','2.8','soda')
```

We see the second line exists, and I want to update it's quantity. The table will look like this:

```
    ('milk 1L','1','1.5','milks')
    ('cola','2','2.5','soda')
    ('bread','1','0.9','pastry')
    ('7up','1','2.8','soda')
```

If the table looks like this:

```
    ('milk 1L','1','1.5','milks')
    ('bread','1','0.9','pastry')
    ('7up','1','2.8','soda')
```

I want to insert the line into the table. So it would look like this:

```
('milk 1L','1','1.5','milks')
('bread','1','0.9','pastry')
('7up','1','2.8','soda')
('cola','1','2.5','soda')
```

Is this posible to do it through a sql query? I need to implement this into a python code. The python part I can handle , but I'm not that good to sql.

Thank you

UPDATE 1:
i forgot to specify maybe the most important thing and this is my fault. I want to check the existence of a `product` `name` inside the `temp_stor` table. Only the name should be unique. If the product exists i wan't to update it's `quantity` value only, if the `product` doesn't exist i want to insert it into the `temp_stor` table.

Comment: Whcih DBMS are you using? You mention MariaDB but have this tagged with mysql and sql server. They are all three different.

Comment: mariadb and mysql are the same, i've updated the tags. i use mariadb. if there is some difference between those 2, i cant tell. i'm not that good with them. but what i've used looked the same

Comment: They aren't really the same since MariaDB is a replacement for mysql but in almost all aspects they are the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [How to connect Python programs to MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-connect-python-programs-mariadb) to see how to connect to your DB.

After that you can select from `temp_stor` the row with the same `id` as the row you have obtained from `products`. Let `row` be the tuple of values you obtained.

```
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM temp_stor WHERE id=%s", (some_id,))
```

If the result of this query contains nothing, indicating that there is no such row, you can proceed to insert it, otherwise, update the row.

```
if len(cursor) == 0:
    try:
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO temp_stor VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""", row)
    except mariadb.Error as error:
        print("Error: {}".format(error))
else:
    cursor.execute ("""
       UPDATE temp_stor
       SET id=%s, name=%s, quantity=%s, price=%s, group=%s
       WHERE id=%s
       """, (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[0]))
```

**Update:**
To perform something similar with just one query:

```
INSERT INTO temp_stor (id, name, quantity, price, group) VALUES(1, "cola", '2.5', 'soda') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity='2.5'
```

Here I am assuming that `1` is the `id` and `"cola"` is the name. If you want `name` to be unique, you should make that the key, because this query currently only compares keys, which in this case seems to be `id`.

Comment: Thanks for the python answer,it's similar to mine but i wanted to know if it's possible to do it with 1 MariaDb command. I know how to do it in python. let's call it a curiosity.

Comment: Normally you would not specify the auto_increment column when using IODKU.  Instead, leave out `id` and `1`.  This is because, if you know the `id`, you may as well do `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "if the data does not exist" means "if the combo of name+quantity+price+group" is is not already there?

Add

```
UNIQUE(name, quantity, price, group)
```

Then

```
INSERT INTO products 
          (name, quantity, price, group)
    SELECT name, quantity, price, group FROM temp_stor;
```

Minor(?) drawback:  This will (I think) 'burn' ids.  In your example, it will allocate 4 new values of `id`, but use only one of them.

**after update to Question**

Do not have the index above, instead, have this.  (I assume `product` is spelled "name"??)

```
UNIQUE(name)
```

Then...

```
INSERT INTO products 
          (name, quantity, price, group)
    SELECT name, quantity, price, group FROM temp_stor
    ON DUPLICATE KEY   -- this will notice UNIQUE(name)
        UPDATE
            quantity = VALUES(quantity);
```

It is unusual to use this construct without `UPDATEing` all the extra columns (quantity, price, group).  What if temp_stor has a different value for `price` or `group`?

Comment: i have updated my question, maybe it will make you understand what i want. i'm not a native english speaker so i strugle sometimes to explain in english want i want.

Comment: hi,  i was on holiday for 2 weeks, now i got back. i tested your update but its not done yet. you are close and i believe there should be some changes. your "formula" it's sincronizing the quantity, i dont want that. i just want to add "1" to the existing quantity. for example if i have 4 bottles of cola i would like to update that quantity like this (4+1). basicaly the `temp_stor` table i use it to sell some products, and its just temporary. after the sale i erase it and insert new products. but i dont want to have the same product twice or more, just to update the product. thank you.